# How do I Prevent alternatingRowBackground for particular columns in DataGrid WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I mean, I don't want alternatingRowBackground for rows in few columns

```
<DataGrid
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AlternationCount="2"
    CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false"
    CanUserDeleteRows="false" CanUserReorderColumns="false" CanUserSortColumns="false"
    FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedRowIndex, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RowHeaderWidth="0"
>
```

Comment: Hi Satish Gurram, welcome to stackoverflow, for us to help you better, could you please share some code, and please be more specific, again welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: <DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AlternationCount="2" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserAddRows = "false" CanUserDeleteRows = "false" CanUserReorderColumns = "false" CanUserSortColumns = "false" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"  ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedRowIndex, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RowHeaderWidth="0">

Comment: Guram you can also edit you own question and post there the code, this time I'll help you with that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CellStyle` property to set different style for cells within a particular column.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AlternationCount="2"
        CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false"
        CanUserDeleteRows="false" CanUserReorderColumns="false" CanUserSortColumns="false"
        FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedRowIndex, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RowHeaderWidth="0">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="WhiteBackgroundCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Prop1}" Header="Prop1" CellStyle="{StaticResource WhiteBackgroundCell}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Prop2}" Header="Prop2" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```